# How to load image efficiently?

Tags: python, image, opencv, ram

1. I have 17,026 webtoon poster image datas(.jpeg/ (256,256,3)) in my google drive folder and their urls
2. I want to cluster by their drawing style.
3. So I loaded data to variable to learn model(I used K-means)
4. but when I done load system ram's state is 3.1/12.7 but..
5. while convert image BOMB!! my system ram explodes.
   (I want to learn not only original image but also canny edge image and HSV image..)

so I have to use my ram efficiently

please help me. is my image data too big (17026*(256*256*3))?

```
os.chdir(image_dir)
files = os.listdir(image_dir)
jpeg_img = []

for file in files:
    if '.jpeg' in file: 
        f = cv2.imread(file)
        jpeg_img.append(f)

edge_X = []
hsv_X = []
#edge 
for img in jpeg_img:
  edge_X.append(cv2.Canny(img,256,256))
edgedX = np.array(edge_X)

for img in jpeg_img:
  hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  hsv_X.append(hsvImage)

hsv_X = np.array(hsv_X)
```

Comment: Clustering large datasets can be a challenge. Have you thought about potentially training a classifier?

Comment: do you need only one variable containing all your images ?
can't you process per image ?

Comment: @JonSG actually I don't knoe about that and my ram explodes before learning ..

Comment: Can you please include your full code? What execatly are you doing? Why not use the Keras image loader API? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory

Comment: @JasonChia 
actually this generates   
Found 0 files belonging to 0 classes.   
Using 0 files for training.   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)   
<ipython-input-15-dd09f4d8cf3d> in <cell line: 1>()   
----> 1 train_data = image_dataset_from_directory(   
      2     directory=image_dir,   
      3     labels='inferred',   
      4     label_mode='categorical',   
      5     batch_size=32,   
ValueError: No images found in directory

Comment: What I am suggesting is that rather than use a clustering strategy, you train an image classifier based on a set of gold labeled images perhaps using keras

Comment: `jpeg_img` ~3.1 GiB. Next `edge_X` is another ~1GiB. `edgedX` yet another 1GiB. Then you populate `hsv_X` with another ~3.1 GiB. And on this you call `np.array(hsv_X)`, which will need further ~3.1 GiB. Not exactly what I'd call efficient use of memory. Both the intermediate lists `edge_X` and `hsv_X` are redundant, you an allocate numpy arrays ahead of time and populate them directly in the loops. That's 35% less memory usage right there.